# How to add line feed in <s:textarea>

Tags: html, struts2

Hi I am using struts 2 UI. I would like to limit the number of characters in  row to 16 and also I have to restrict the maxlength to 32. I tried row and column attirbute. But its not working.Also I have to restrict the resizing of textarea. Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you had a typo?  The attributes are "rows" and "cols", not "row" and "column".

The following should work:

```
<s:textarea key="yourDataField" cols="32" rows="16" resizable="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice explanation how to restrict the [resizing of textareas](http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/)

```
<s:textarea cssStyle="resize: none;"></s:textarea>
```

should do the job.